# Why Ubuntu 18.04LTS takes >1.6GB after start?

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, memory-usage

i have Ubuntu 18.04LTS (+updates etc.)
i've just recently noticed, that after restart, already 1.6GB of RAM is taken... why?
I know there is a Docker service, fine (87MB ?), but i was expecting ~600MB of RAM used ...
that's htop screenshot right after logging in.
Can you help me identify problem ?

[image: htop screenshot]

```
sudo free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        1,2G         12G        495M        1,7G         13G
Swap:           19G          0B         19G
```

Comment: Pls update your question with the output of `sudo free -h`.

Comment: I'm almost sure that the output of ´free -h´ will show that most of the "RAM Usage" will be buffered/cached and not actually in use.

Comment: sudo free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        1,2G         12G        495M        1,7G         13G
Swap:           19G          0B         19G

I've just added output to my post